# Decoding and Printing Json Data into html table using php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have the following encoded json array:

```
function getMostActive($link) {
    $query = "SELECT username AS staff, COUNT(*) As Total FROM vloer_action_logs WHERE task_type = 'job_status_change' AND accessed_time >= '2019-12-31' AND accessed_time <= '2020-01-06'
Group by username ORDER BY 2 DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    if (!$result)
        die(mysqli_error($link));

    $jsonData = array();
    while ($array = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $jsonData[] = $array;
    }
    return json_encode($jsonData);
}
```

I wanted to print this data in a table. Tried the following

```
$getMostActive = json_decode(getMostActive($link),true);
<?php foreach ($getMostActive as $key=>$value) { ?>
    <tr>
     <td class="dark"><?php echo $value['Floor'];?> </td>
     <td class="end"><?php echo $value['Total'];?></td>
    </tr>
```

But it is throwing me error:

> Trying to get property 'Floor' of non-object in
>   /var/www/html/users/reports/report.php

How can i solve this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your error says it's trying to get the property of an object, yet your code only refers to `Floor` as an array index.  This would give you a different message.

Comment: @NigelRen the error message says he's trying to get a property of a **non-object**. Notice the true as the second parameter of the json_decode.

Comment: @Vkfan, the message would only come from something like `$value->Floor`, `$value['Floor']` would give `Undefined index: Floor`

Comment: @NigelRen you're right on this one. The only thing I can assume is that the error message is outdated and the code originally referenced $value as an object. Also sorry, I just realized I misinterpreted your earlier comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many have said, already, your query in the first line of the getMostActive() function doesn't select any field named *Floor*. For this reason, the moment you decode the json, you get an array similar to this one:

```
[
  [
    "staff" => "name1",
    "Total" => 5
  ],
  [
    "staff" => "name2",
    "Total" => 3
  ]
  // [...]
]
```

with none of the entries representing the single rows containing the *Floor* field you're looking for.

To check, temporarily place the following code right before your table

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($getMostActive);
```

then fix the query. For what I can see, everything else is correct.

Hope I've been of any help.

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of mistakes there. First of all the JSON that you are trying to decode must be a string. And you are also missing a $ when you are decoding.

Here is the working code:

```
<?php 

$getMostActive = '[{"Floor":"carpet","Total":"22"},{"Floor":"ceramic-tiles","Total":"13"},{"Floor":"hardwood","Total":"13"}]';

$getMostActive = json_decode($getMostActive,true);
?>

<table>
<?php
foreach ($getMostActive as $key=>$value) { 

?>
    <tr>
     <td class="dark"><?php echo $value['Floor'];?> </td>
     <td class="end"><?php echo $value['Total'];?></td>
    </tr>
<?php 
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: From you query it seems you are not fetching `Floor` as the query has `SELECT username AS staff, COUNT(*) As Total`. Have you checked you are getting Floor in result of query?

Answer (score 0):

Try below one.

```
    $getMostActive = '[{"Floor":"carpet","Total":"22"},{"Floor":"ceramic-tiles","Total":"13"},{"Floor":"hardwood","Total":"13"}]';
$getMostActive = json_decode($getMostActive,true);
 foreach ($getMostActive as $key=>$value) { ?>
    <tr>
     <td class="dark"><?php echo $value['Floor'];?> </td>
     <td class="end"><?php echo $value['Total'];?></td>
    </tr>
 <?php } ?>
```

looks your JSON data is not correct, check the `single quote`.

Comment: Getting this error `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in`

Comment: try to print $getMostActive and see the result.

Comment: Please check the single quote, if you use your JSON content.